# How to assert that all $ReadOnlyArray members are of certain type?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have tried iterating the array using `for..of` and throwing an exception if the type does not match:

```
type FooPacketType = 'foo';
type BarPacketType = 'bar';

type PacketType =
  FooPacketType |
  BarPacketType;

const packets: $ReadOnlyArray<PacketType> = [];

function ingestFooPackets(fooPackets: $ReadOnlyArray<FooPacketType>) {}

for (const packet of packets) {
  if (packet !== 'foo') {
    throw new Error('Unexpected state');
  }
}

ingestFooPackets(packets);
```

This gives an error:

```
18: ingestFooPackets(packets);
                     ^ Cannot call `ingestFooPackets` with `packets` bound to `fooPackets` because string literal `bar` [1] is incompatible with string literal `foo` [2] in array element.
References:
8: const packets: $ReadOnlyArray<PacketType> = [];
                                 ^ [1]
10: function ingestFooPackets(fooPackets: $ReadOnlyArray<FooPacketType>) {}
                                                         ^ [2]
```

https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAYg9nACgQwMYGsLACrmgXigHIAzBIgbgChRIoAhZAJxQy1zsKICNnKqaeKK0w4h+KlFgIR7IQB9JDZrLGRqVVHAB2AZ2BQwaUboBcUACQAlCMgAmAeW0AbEAEEmTZCAA8qjhAAfFCEANoAuhokAK7aqMAAljpQCdoA5hD68EjGWLoAFGQ5bMBmljb2Tq4eXr7Z-niBAJRQAN4AvgJkTFD5WnoGRiVQcCSGuaUtrUoJY-lDolAAhPhcRURTSlLAABZMcADuUNoQRwCinnBM+UQAqicAHpDxEHZQ+sjAEBvUUp2dVFSGSyMgmBQWeSaFCAA

I am unsure if this is a bug (I have [raised an issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7165)) or if there is another way to assert that all members of array are of certain type.